# How to generate the javascript behind the tag by ScriptManager class

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I want to use the ScriptManager class to generate the javascript that behind the  tag .  but I Don't know which method shuold i use...... the position must behind  tag

My English sucks, wish to express clearly...

Comment: Consider re-framing your question ? Not clear what exactly you want.

Comment: Try to explain what you want to achieve instead of how to implement your decision.

Comment: Please provide exact scenario which you want to develop..

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you need, but if you need to register some client script, use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "scriptName", "your java script", true);
```

or if you need to register a script that runs when the page loads, use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "scriptName", "your javascript", true);
```